# An interesting bet

Tags: logical-deduction, wordplay

Someone comes to you and says: 'I bet you £1, that if you give me £2 I will give you £3 in return. Do you accept my offer?' What do you respond to him?

Comment: any reasoning for the change? sounds like an opinionated question if that is the case which it seems like.

Comment: it actually changes the meaning of the question in a way, since the word **promise** is eradicated.

Comment: I would take the bet and then never give them £2

Comment: @hexomino "if a, then b" is true whenever "a" is false, so you would just be out a dollar.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 Ah, but "If a, then not b" is also true so I take that dollar back.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93: Typical wagering terms would be that if A bets B \$1 at even odds that Y will happen if X happens, then A will pay B \$1 if X happens and Y doesn't, B will pay A \$1 if X and Y both happen, and *neither party will pay the other* if X doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The statement is quite confusing, so simplifying it is a must. So, after some rejigging -
> If you give me £2, I may give you £3. The bet is £1 that this will happen
> I've substituted "promise" for "may", because it's essentially the same thing, but makes more sense when dealing with probabilities. The case is whether you trust them or not:

> You trust them
> Well done you, now let's see the consequences:
>  1. You give them £2
> You: -£2
> Them: £2
> 2. They give you £3
> You: £1
> Them: -£1
> 3. They win, so you give them £1
> You: £0
> Them: £0
> That was pointless!

> You don't trust them
> Erring on the side of caution are we? Let's see what could happen:
>  1. You give them £2
> You: -£2
> Them: £2
>  2. They break their promise, and don't give you £3
> You: -£2
> Them: £2
> The statement did not happen, so they give you £1
> You: -£1
> Them: £1
> Oh dear, you could lose £1 as well

> You skew your own chances on purpose
> The other alternative is that you don't give them the £2 to start with, although you'd seem pretty stupid to do this
> 1. You don't give them £2
> You: £0
> Them: £0
> They don't give you £3, because it's dependant on you giving them £2
> You: £0
> Them: £0
> You did not induce the conditional statement, so nothing else happens
> You: £0
> Them: £0
> This seems strange, because you'd think you'd have to give them £1, but you never chanced it. A clear example makes this obvious
> I bet you £10 that if Red Rum comes first, Lightning will come second
> If the condition (Red Rum comes first) never occurs, the bet has no pay-out

> As there is no way you can possibly make money on this, no matter how truthful they are, you should NOT take the bet

Comment: Whoops - I'm thinking of poker betting (both parties bet the same amount). I'll adjust my answer

Comment: Of course there are at least two other possibilities, they might give you more than £3 back . Also, you can take the bet and never give £2 (although here the monetary position remains unchanged).

Comment: Yeah, I suppose, but if I were to account for every single scenario, it would be very long, and be very boring. For example, the odds that they kill me after I gave them £2 are very unlikely!

Comment: I've just realised the third outcome is wrong @hexomino, the statement describes not giving £2, but I've done different sums for some reason. I'll adjust it now

Answer (score 6):

You should

> reject the offer if you prefer having more money to having less money,

because

> they can take your £2, *not* promise you £3 in return, pay you £1 for losing the bet, and end up taking £1 from you overall.

Comment: interesting. but based off the problem statement, if you give £2, the one betting has to receive £3 (profit of £1) as it's a promise.

Comment: @FishingCode Nope: the promise itself is subject to the bet. "I bet that _if_ you give me £2 _then_ I promise to give you £3". (In the original wording, which OP has since edited.) It's not "I promise that if you give me £2 then I will give you £3, and I bet £1 that I actually will". Though even in the latter case, the fact that they're proposing the bet seems to indicate that their promise is in some doubt, and I still wouldn't take them up on the offer.

Comment: I think the reason why this answer works becomes crystal clear if you replace £2 and £3 with two higher quantities in the original statement, for example "I bet you £1, that if you give me £100 I will give you £500 in return"

Answer (score 1):

Should you take this bet?

> Yes. But don't give them anything.

Because:

> The premise that your bet is founded on is "if you give me £2 I will give you £3 in return". As a logical proposition, this is equivalent to saying that "you give them £2" implies "they will give you £3".

> Mathematically speaking, an implication is true whenever either the first proposition is false or the second one is true. (E.g., "If pigs have wings, then I'm a monkey's uncle" is mathematically true because pigs don't have wings, regardless of my personal family connections. There's no way for this statement to be proven false except by producing winged swine.)

> So as long as you *don't* give them any money, then the first clause is false ("you give them £2"), making the entire implication true according to propositional logic. And since that's what you're betting on, you win the bet, and they have to give you £1. So you come out of it £1 richer.

Answer (score 0):

> Interesting question for sure...kinda like one of those teasers but here's my approach/answer to it:

> The person being challenged here, should **accept** the offer. As he/she **could** walk away with a **£2** profit if that persons agree to deal/bet with the person who is initializing the bet. Because, when you give £2 and the person promises to give you £3 in return, that is not including the **initial** bet he/she placed with you (the challenger) so we have to account for the £1 bet to be included in the profit (£3 - £2).

Comment: now it is an open-ended question :)

Comment: exactly, right. because in your other answer you had just provided, it would be a loss and not a profit for the bet-initializer.

Comment: I don't see how the original wording helps this answer at all.  The original wording was nonsensical, but I can't find any way to interpret in a way that makes the person considering the offer gain $2.  If anything, "I bet that I will make a promise to you" is even worse.